# How much does Alicia earn?

Tags: the-good-wife

In at least season one of *The Good Wife*, it is heavily emphasized that Alicia is returning to work to support her family. Is it ever mentioned how much she earns at Stern, Lockhart & Gardner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**We don't know for sure.**

However, we can speculate.

In season 1, she returns to the firm as an associate. The range of possible salaries open to her are dependent on a few things including the size of the firm and her level of experience. However, [we can use existing information](http://www.nalp.org/2011_associate_salaries) to guesstimate that she stared in Season 1 on somewhere between $73,000 and $160,000.

Of course, if she came in at a higher level than that, she could be higher on the scale. For example, the average eighth year associate earns between $111,250 and $225,000.

On a separate note, there are quite a few fashion blogs online that admire [her range of clothing](http://thehairpin.com/2015/05/every-single-outfit-alicia-florrick-wears-in-every-episode-of-the-good-wife/). They've identified quite a few items from [Armani](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj1xafqk4LLAhXG_A4KHS8FDYMQFggoMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.armani.com%2Fgb&usg=AFQjCNFRCqOtBAefCxJKQaXzN0q42n5Vhw&sig2=RoBxf4WNdZedEq1NOw1tsA), [Michael Kors](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiw87Lsk4LLAhXKsxQKHZxzC78QFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.michaelkors.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNFS0q-bZRVr7D7CHeJd0utOqpfYpw&sig2=Rto7tGPiMhHRVp_NbtGo6w), [Rena Lange](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiNht32k4LLAhWFchQKHUGqB9wQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yoox.com%2Fuk%2Fwomen%2Fshoponline%2Frena%2520lange_d&usg=AFQjCNEX0HngD4nsbEyWTMH2j4okD8lc1w&sig2=6UctGzHQUot2RLbBTaWnmQ) and the like, so she's certainly not struggling!